# SQL Server using Having clause on data returned by subquery

Tags: php, sql-server, having

```
SELECT  id ,
        idUser ,
        szEAN ,
        szMeterAddressConcat ,
        szCommodity ,
        szChannelConcat ,
        szEmail ,
        iProcessedFlag ,
        dtCreated ,
        iStatus ,
        iActive ,
        iIgnore ,
        iNumEanCount
FROM    ( SELECT    MAX(met.id) AS id ,
                    MAX(met.idUser) AS idUser ,
                    MAX(met.szEAN) AS szEAN ,
                    MAX(met.szMeterAddress) AS szMeterAddressConcat ,
                    MAX(met.szCommodity) AS szCommodity ,
                    MAX(met.szChannel) AS szChannelConcat ,
                    MAX(met.szEmail) AS szEmail ,
                    MAX(met.iProcessedFlag) AS iProcessedFlag ,
                    MAX(met.dtCreated) AS dtCreated ,
                    MAX(met.iStatus) AS iStatus ,
                    MAX(met.iActive) AS iActive ,
                    MAX(met.iIgnore) AS iIgnore ,
                    ( SELECT    COUNT(el.IDan)
                      FROM      dbo.tblean el
                      WHERE     el.EAN = met.szEAN
                                AND el.isDeleted = 0
                    ) AS iNumEanCount ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY MAX(met.szEAN) ASC ) AS 'RowNumber'
          FROM      dbo.tblcustomermeterlist AS met
          WHERE     met.isDeleted = '0'
          GROUP BY  szEAN
          HAVING    MAX(iNumEanCount) > 0
        ) AS mt
WHERE   mt.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25
```

I am trying to use `HAVING` clause on iNumEanCount. Can anybody let me know what I am doing wrong in above query?

Comment: why you suppose you are doing wrong? is there any error? the result is not the one you expect? please add details.

Comment: instead of putting having in sub query you can also put it in where clause lke `iNumEanCount > 0` after your between statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your quick responses. I made little changes to my query and it is working fine for me. here i am posting the changes what i have made.

```
SELECT 
                id,
                idUser,
                szEAN, 
                szMeterAddressConcat,
                szCommodity,
                szChannelConcat,
                szEmail,
                iProcessedFlag,
                dtCreated,
                iStatus,
                iActive, 
                iIgnore,
                iNumEanCount
            FROM ( 
               SELECT  
                  MAX(met.id) as id,
                  MAX(met.idUser) as idUser,
                  MAX(met.szEAN) as szEAN,
                  MAX(met.szMeterAddress) as szMeterAddressConcat,
                  MAX(met.szCommodity) as szCommodity,
                  MAX(met.szChannel) as szChannelConcat,
                  MAX(met.szEmail) as szEmail,
                  MAX(met.iProcessedFlag) as iProcessedFlag,
                  MAX(met.dtCreated) as dtCreated,
                  MAX(met.iStatus) as iStatus,
                  MAX(met.iActive) as iActive, 
                  MAX(met.iIgnore) as iIgnore,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY MAX(met.szEAN) ASC) AS 'RowNumber',
                  (SELECT count(el.IDan) FROM dbo.tblean el WHERE el.EAN = met.szEAN AND el.isDeleted
=0) as iNumEanCount
               FROM 
                  dbo.tblcustomermeterlist  as met
              WHERE
                  met.isDeleted = '0'

                   GROUP BY szEAN   
            ) AS mt    
                 WHERE mt.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25
                 AND iNumEanCount > 0
```